# Changing some Eclipse preferences using java

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on a Eclipse plugin and I want to change some settings for the user in able to be able to use the plugin correctly

I need to make some changes in the settings of Eclipse using the code instead
**For example:**
If I want to access Window-Open perspective-Debug
Instead of telling the user these steps, I want to make it in the code 
Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific, otherwise you're only going to end up at http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/user_settings/faq.html .  Your example is a bad one since you shouldn't be changing the perspective without the user's consent.  Even then, that's not a Preference, that's an API call: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchWindow.html#openPage(java.lang.String, org.eclipse.core.runtime.IAdaptable) .

Your plug-in **should not require** the user to be in any specific perspective.  They should be free to arrange the editor and views any way they like.

Comment: The perspective example is just an example to show the meaning of [change some Eclipse preferences] .. I'll need to change the encoding to UTF8 in more than one place to enable the user to write Arabic in the Console .. Any help?

Comment: Depends on where the "more than one place" places are.  For that, the user settings would probably be the right way to change them.

Comment: So there's no way that I could change the setting for him ?        Here is one of the things I want to change                          Eclipse-Preferences-General-Workspace-Text file encoding